# Unable to create report on approvals in sfdc

Tags: apex, soql, approval-process

Hi friends i have a standard approval process in account.And in some scenarios the accounts submitted for approval multiple times.So, my requirement is to create a report for approvals in account.So, i create a custom report type but i need fields in account object.

So, for this requirement i need to add another child object to the account.And try to create a record when in goes for approval as specified below link

https://cherfeldman.blogspot.in/2014/01/potential-solution-for-reporting-on.html?showComment=1472502144116#c9027830380141607440

But,in my case is standard approval.User manually submits record for approval.So,I am confused to solve this issue.Please provide your suggestions for this requirement.

Comment: [OOB Approval process Reports using Custom Report Type](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=approval_history_reports.htm&language=en_US) unfortunately don't let you show related object fields as these are polymorphic lookups. I'd use a VF controller that created a report or a clever Conga Composer excel template

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution to my requirement.Because we want to keep track whether the record is approved or rejected or recalled.

So,for this requirement i create a new object and create a master detail relationship and whenever any record is either rejected or approved or recalled.I am creating a child record and referencing the fields to track for that specific approval time.

So,now it's keep tracking all the approval requests.